# Shared service works only onInit - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript, observable

I want to pass an object between 2 components. I created the following shared service:

```
[PageService Component]
    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
    changeMessage(message) {
        this.messageSource.next(message)
    }
```

And I have implemented it in these 2 components:

```
[COMPONENT WHEN I GET ON CLICK SONO DATAS]
constructor(private pageService: PageService, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
...
onClickMethod(){
self.pageService.getCustomers(self.filters).toPromise().then(response => {
      self.searchResults = response;
    });
     self.pageService.changeMessage(self.searchResults);
}
```

and

```
[Component where I need to see above datas]
ngOnInit() {
    let self = this;
     self.pageService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => self.searchResults = message);
    console.log(self.searchResults);

  }
```

Now...if I put the "changeMessage" method in the first component in the method onInit or in the costructor and i try to pass some data like [1,2,3] (so not the response of another api rest) it seems to work...this doesn't work just when i put it inside onClick method and passing "self.searchResults" (the response)...anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: can you a minimal demo in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Go from this

```
self.pageService.getCustomers(self.filters).toPromise().then(response => {
  self.searchResults = response;
});
self.pageService.changeMessage(self.searchResults);
```

To this

```
self.pageService.getCustomers(self.filters).toPromise().then(response => {
  self.searchResults = response;
  self.pageService.changeMessage(self.searchResults);
});
```

Because you make an HTTP call (I assume), you should wait for the call to end. In your code, it doesn't.